# To add all the values of a specific subkey for a dictionary python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

so consider a dictionary.

```
{
"b0:47:bf:af:c1:42": 
{
 "No. of visits": 10, "cities": 
     {
      "Mumbai": {"count": 5,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Kolkata": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Amritsar":{"count": 3,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
     }
},
"c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d": 
 {
 "No. of visits": 24, "cities": 
     {
      "Mumbai": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Kolkata": {"count": 20,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Amritsar":{"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
     }
  }
 }
```

so what i want is to sum all the `"count"` for all the `"cities"` my output will have the same value as `"No. of visits"`, obviously I am asking the question not specifically for this context. I am using python2.7

well I was iterating to get some values when I realized I might need to get value of `"No. of visits"` with out using it(it might not be there for every key).

```
for mac in dic_data:

cities = dic_data[mac]['cities']
most_visited = max(cities, key=lambda x: cities[x]['count'])
```

so I was just trying to know how can I get sum of "count" of all "cities" each mac.I just want `sum_of_count = sum(something here)` which gives output as sum of count `10` for first key and `24` for second key.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You say "my output will have the same value as `"No. of visits"`" but then why bother adding up the counts? Why not just use `"No of visits"`? What exactly is your intended output for the example dictionary you've shown?

Comment: Do you wish to find a total sum or a sum for each id?

Comment: What have you considered before posting it here? What code have you tried?

Comment: @Blckknght as I mentioned further in question tat I am not asking specifically for this context. I have to do this type of things, So I am trying to understand this by asking a example.

Comment: Well, your question isn't very meaningful without any coherent context. If your real problem is something too complicated, you can simplify it. But you need to give us something to go on, to understand what you are asking for. Give some example output for the example input and maybe you'll get a proper answer. Right now, people can only guess what you want because you haven't said.

Comment: @MoonCheesez I wasn't able to do this thing that's why I asked, I have looked onto things, it is easy to add keys' value but for sub key sum() doesn't takes argument like max() `max(cities, key=lambda x: cities[x]['count'])` . So, I asked here.

Comment: @ranadan It would be better if you could include code that you have considered so that we would have a better idea of what you want to do and what you have tried that did not work so that others would not answer with what you have tried already again.

Comment: Again, my question is: do you wish to find a total sum or a sum for each id?

Comment: @zondo for each id.

Comment: @MoonCheesez added some thing that might clear my question.

Comment: @MoonCheesez  is it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate through each mac address `sum()` the `count`s then find the `max()`. Assuming your data is stored in the variable `data`, here is the one statement version:

```
max([sum([data[visit]["cities"][city]["count"] for city in data[visit]["cities"]]) for visit in data])
```

Here is the for loop version with comments:

```
# This list will store all the total no. of visits of each mac address
counts = []
for mac in data:
    # This variable will keep track of the number of visits in the current mac address
    visits = 0
    for city in data[mac]["cities"]:
        visits += data[mac]["cities"][city]["count"]
    counts.append(visits)
# Get the highest number of visits
print max(counts)
```

Comment: thanx for your answer :), that is what I didn't wanted running one more loop, but I guess that's the only way.

Comment: @ranadan The minimum amount of loops you can have is two. One to for each mac address and one to iterate through each city to `sum()` the count.

Comment: yes, thanx for the explanation. Btw how did all the other answer vanished.
P.S. I am new to this site.

Comment: @ranadan I don't know why but they deleted their answers.